# PDO complex fetch mode

Tags: php, pdo

Just being curious, if let say I have sql returning data in this structure

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'article.id' => '1001',
        'article.title' => 'lorem ipsum',
        'article.body' => 'dolor sit',
        'user.id' => '2012',
        'user.name' => 'foo',
        'user.email' => 'foo@example.com'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'article.id' => '1001',
        'article.title' => 'lorem ipsum',
        'article.body' => 'dolor sit',
        'user.id' => '2013',
        'user.name' => 'bar',
        'user.email' => 'bar@example.com'
    )
);
```

As you can see both actually refers to the same article but co-written by 2 different users, without using any other ORM/DB library and just plain PDO, how would you make the data returned from the database into this form:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'article.id' => '1001',
        'article.title' => 'lorem ipsum',
        'article.body' => 'dolor sit',
        'user' => array(
            0 => array(
                'user.id' => '2012',
                'user.name' => 'foo',
                'user.email' => 'foo@example.com'
            ),
            1 => array(
                'user.id' => '2013',
                'user.name' => 'bar',
                'user.email' => 'bar@example.com'
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

And, which DB library (if possible, without ORM) can do this without a lot of effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a JOIN to retrieve both the article and the user data in a single query, why not do two separate queries, one to retrieve the articles and the second to retrieve the user data who's relevant to the articles? It is surely simpler and is probably more efficient.

Comment: what if i have more than just 2 rows returned and it has a lot of articles co-written by many different authors? would that still be better if I separate the one large query into 2?

Answer (score 0):

It is no a good practice to use this method in PDO class. PDO works with DB and should returns structured data. You can write your own function, that will do manipulations with returned array.